# How to recursively pass through every n elements from an array into a function

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming, and I have been working on a javascript problem for the past couple of days.

Essentially, I need to write a function that takes in three parameters: an array `arr`, a function `fn` to be called repeatedly, and a value `step` that signifies how many elements from the array to pass into fn.

For example, if `step` were 3, then `fn` would be called with the first 3 elements of `arr` each as a positional argument. `fn` will be called again with the next 3 arguments. `fn` will continue to be called until there are no more elements to use as arguments from `arr`. If the last group of arguments is less than `step`, call the function `fn` with whatever arguments are left.

I am pretty new to recursion. I have watched lots of videos and was attempting practice problems from my textbook and this was one of the ones I had trouble with.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does the function return anything?

Comment: This problem doesn't involve recursion. If this is a learning exercise, post what you've tried, and we can advise from there.

Comment: I agree with @fubar. Seems like a simple loop would solve this:

function arrayHandler(arr, cb, nArgs) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += nArgs) {
        cb(arr[i], arr[i+1], arr[i+2]);
    }
}

Comment: @yccteam, you may want to use `Array.prototype.slice`, because your solution doesn't support a change in the step values.

Comment: the function fn being called is unknown. we dont know what the function does or returns.  @fubar, also the problem is supposed to be solved with recursion. I tried using a while arr not empty loop and inside a for loop that iterates to step elements, puts them in a diff array, then passes the values of that to fn but I am not supposed to use any loops and the problem is supposed to be solved only with recursion ;(

Comment: @fubar - I didn't understand that from the specifications. arrayHandler should be called once only. Did I get this wrong?

Comment: @yccteam, my understanding was that the `step` value could change. But your call to `cb(arr[i], arr[i+1], arr[i+2])` passes through a fixed number of parameters.

Comment: these are the examples i got: steppedForEach([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], (a, b, c) => console.log('' + a + b + c),  3);
/* 
note that arrow function is called twice, each time with 3 elements from arr:
123
456
*/
steppedForEach([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], (a, b, c) => console.log('' + a + b + c),  3);
/*
in this case, the arrow function is called 3 times, but the last time, only one
argument is passed in, 7 (there are no more elements after that)
123
456
7undefinedundefined
*/  Note stepForEach is the name of the method I am implementing

Comment: @PranayPatel, I see. I didn't understand that you **had** to use recusion. I thought this was your suggestion. Have you managed to attempt this yourself?

Comment: @fubar ofc! I honestly don't even know how to tackle this without loops. my guess, even with recurssion, would be to have a while loop with a for loop that iterates through the array and recurses through every "step" elements and that is what I tried but came to find out I can't include any loops. :/

Comment: @fubar - you are correct. Happens when you are trying to think at 1 A.M.  :)

Answer (score 0):

if you have to use recursive function you can try

```js
function withRecursion(array, fn, value){
  //take an amount of arguments equal to value by slicing the array
  fn( ...array.slice(0, value) );
  //if the length of array is lower then value this means that this was the last elements of the array
  if(value < array.length){
    //give the function the rest of the array by removing the elements we already used
    withRecursion(array.slice(value, array.length), fn, value); 
  }
}

function test(...args){
  for(var arg of args){
    console.log(arg);
  }
  console.log("test finished");
}

withRecursion([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], test, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want a function that processes data in steps:

```js
var arrayToProcess = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

function myRecursiveFunction(step, fn, arr) {
  // if the step is greater that the array, process and return
  if (arr.length <= step) {
    fn(arr);
    return;
  }
  // else take out the part of the array that you will process on this step
  myRecursiveFunction(step, fn, arr.slice(step));
  // process the array with only the element belonging to the step
  fn(arr.slice(0, step));
  return;

}

myRecursiveFunction(3, (function(arr) {
  console.log(arr);
}), arrayToProcess);
```

So, what's going to happen is that we're going to be calling the recursive function with these inputs in this order:

1. `myRecursiveFunction(3, fn, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])`
2. `myRecursiveFunction(3, fn, [4,5,6,7,8])`
3. `myRecursiveFunction(3, fn, [7,8])`

Which in turn will execute the input `fn` in this order:

1. `fn([7,8])`
2. `fn([4,5,6])`
3. `fn([1,2,3])`

Our stop condition is if the `arr` is smaller then the step: `arr.length <= step` else, we will continue recursion and also process the first `step` elements of the `arr`.

If you want to understand how the slice function works you can look at it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice